# Solaris 10 Server doesn't auto execute php files

Tags: php, unix

I have a server that runs on Solaris 10, whenever I go to the address, it displays as directory with all the files and folders instead of execute the index.php file.

Is there any way to stop it from displaying directory and execute the php files automatically?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so
AddHandler php5-script .php
AddType text/html .php
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Comment: it's working now, thanks alot. I didn't add the `directoryindex`

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking of a web server, such as Apache, you should configure it with a PHP specific module, such as mod_php ... or with a CGI executor (php-cgi executable) with some URI rules so that it can execute PHP files instead of just displaying them.

Typically, index.php files are configured with a separate directive to allow them as Default documents in a directory, like index.html

Comment: yea, that's what I was going for, but I didn't know to how put it that way

Comment: `AddType application/x-httpd-php .php` in an apache config file. Asked many times before http://serverfault.com/questions/375788/apache22-displays-php-source

Comment: Wherever your httpd.conf is, or as a separate .conf file in conf.d directories.

Comment: I mean, where inside the httpd.conf?

Comment: See this guide - what you should do is follow the PHP5 and Apache conf - http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Running_MediaWiki_on_Solaris_10#Apache2

Comment: I added the line inside <IfModule mod_mime.c>, but it still doesn't work

Comment: That's a wrong module you're comparing... You should be using - IfModule mod_php5.c .. Typically, a successful LoadModule php5_module causes future execution of IfModule mod_php5.c to pass.